# What is the best convergence measure of MCMC

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, convergence

I use measures of Gelman and Rubin or Geweke. However, they are not applicable to sampling from multi-modal distribution, say p(x), because a chain can be stuck in a local mode. In such cases, the chain seems to be stationary and the two convergence measures will give a bad result that it is safe to terminate sampling, actually it is not. When I handled toy problems, I set first or second moment of target distributions is known. The distance between the value and its approximation using the corresponding chain was used as a convergence measure, but it is practically not applicable.

Is there any MCMC convergence measure that makes use of target distributions?

Comment: Could you please add references to the measures you mentioned?

Comment: What do you mean 'makes use of target distributions'? General convergence measures should only use MCMC samples.

Comment: Both Gelman-Rubin and Geweke are applicable to multi-model distributions, but they will both give misleading results if all chains are in a single mode.

Comment: I answered a similar question [Convergence of MCMC for ill-behaved functions] (https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/391215/7224).